How to set polling on RTK, every 24h
component:
import { useGetUserNotificationsQuery } from "../../../../api_v2/notifications";

const { data: userNotifications, isFetching: loadingNotifications } =
  useGetUserNotificationsQuery();

useEffect(() => {
  if (userNotifications) {
    const unreadedNots = userNotifications?.filter(
      (notif) => notif.read === false
    );
    setUnreadedNotifications(unreadedNots);
  }
}, [userNotifications]);

Can't figure out how to set polling every 24h. My goal to refresh data only every 24h and I don't need to get data immediately, when component mounted.
I was thinking about lazy query and timer state with setInterval, but not sure that it's the right way.

Query hooks take an options object that includes a pollingInterval property that can be enabled/configured.
See:

Query Hook Options
Polling Overview
useQuery

The following should allow you to instantiate the query subscription and poll on a 24 hour interval.
const TWENTY_FOUR_HOURS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours in milliseconds

const { ... } = useGetUserNotificationsQuery(
  /* arg or undefined */,
  {
    pollingInterval: TWENTY_FOUR_HOURS
  }
);

Lazy Query Hooks include the same pollingInterval option that works the same from when the lazy query is initiated, i.e. when it is triggered.
const [trigger, { ... }] = useLazyGetUserNotificationsQuery({
  pollingInterval: TWENTY_FOUR_HOURS
});

...

trigger(/* arg or undefined */);


Am i right get it, pollingInterval will triggered query when component mounted and then every interval in polling?

@DavidAbramov Yes, pollingInterval will automatically re-run the query on the specified interval. If you use a useQuery hook the first query is made on the initial render cycle. With the useLazyQuery hook the first query is made when the trigger is called.

Hmm, without first arg in hook, polling not working for me: const { data } = useGetUserNotificationsQuery("test", {
pollingInterval: 1000,
})

@DavidAbramov Shoot, sorry about that, yeah, useQuery expects the query arg first, then the options. I've updated.
